# Understanding JS objects defined as functions vs not defined as functions

Tags: javascript, object

Relative JS newbie here trying to understand the difference between two ways of defining a JS object...

In certain cases I have seen examples of what I would call "namespace" objects or "handlers" that might look something like this:

```
var example = {
  message: null,
  setup: function( message ) {
    example.message = message;
    alert( message );
  }
}
```

I might use something like this to group some related functions. If I were to call `example('foo!')` I would expect an alert message with `foo!` to appear, and thereafer if I called `example.message` I would expect it to return `foo!`.

*My first question is: what is this kind of object (not defined as a function) called?*

I use objects like this a lot in my sites, as handlers to setup a bunch of bindings for ajax interactions etc. I've been trying to learn about object-oriented javascript, and have been doing some reading ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript),[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)). In the Mozilla docs it's suggested that objects should be defined as functions, so more like this:

```
var example = function( message ) {
    ....
}
```

*My second question is: What is this kind of object (defined as a function) called?*

I don't really understand the difference between the two so I'm having a number of issues, which raises question 3:

*If you define an object as a function, how do you define properties on the object if you don't necessarily want them to execute when it is instantiated?*

Ie. if I do this:

```
var example = function( message ) {
    alert('message');
}
```

Then I know that `example('foo!')` will trigger an alert with `foo!`. But, how do I define other properties or methods on the object to access and/or call later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My first question is: what is this kind of object (not defined as a
>   function) called?

That is knows as *[object literal notation](http://www.fotiweb.com/2006/12/13/javascript-object-literal-notation/).*

> My second question is: What is this kind of object (defined as a
>   function) called?

That is knows as *[function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)*.

**More Readings:**

- [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)
- [Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

> If you define an object as a function, how do you define properties on
>   the object if you don't necessarily want them to execute when it is
>   instantiated?

You can use `this` keyword to add properties or use `prototype` property like this:

```
var example = function( message ) {
    alert('message');
    this.hello = function(){
        alert('hello'); 
    }
}
```

Or

```
var example = function( message ) {
    alert('message');
}

example.prototype.hello = function(){ 
   alert('hello');
}

var e = new example('hello');
e.hello();
```

When using `this`, you need to use `new` keyword to instantiate the object.

---

**Interested readings on OOP:**

- [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
- [Object-Oriented JavaScript: Create scalable, reusable high-quality JavaScript applications and libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141) by Stoyan Stefanov

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you! One minor subquestion, are there any major *gotchas* or tricky differences between object literal and function expression? Ie. since I'm used to using obj. literals is there anything I should be especially wary of if I try to use a function expression?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting, but if you omit `new` from `e = new example`, `this` in the `example` function refers to the global object (`window`).